# Selecting multiple items from a list with JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to figure out how to select multiple items from a list of options. Currently, I have a jQuery I use to select items that contain a certain number. For instance, if you look at the screenshot below, I have selected only those options with the numbers **'03'**.

The script I use to do this is:

```
$('#formfields option[title*="(##)"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

[image: selectedItems]

The HTML SELECT and OPTION looks as follows:

```
<select id="formfields" name="formfields" divclass="" optionsonly="false" size="10" fromselect="false" class="mcdropDown"
title="Form Fields" multiple="" required="" aria-required="true">
<option value="2O5W6XNX5ZCSDLW6GK" title="Completion Documentation - mastercontrol.links.Completion (01)">Completion Documentation - mastercontrol.links.Completion (01)</option>
```

Clearly, there are TONS more options that that.

Now, I have a similar list, but the HTML SELECTS and OPTIONS are a bit different. Here is a screenshot of the list I am trying to work with.

[image: itemsToMove]

I'd like to be able to do something similar as above. There are hundreds of options in some of these lists and I only need to move certain items over to the 'currently selected' window. For instance, can I write a jQuery or JS to select only those items that say InfoCard Employee, InfoCard File Name, InfoCard Owner... and so on?

The issue is that the HTML SELECTS and OPTIONS aren't being very generous in the accessibility of the elements.

Here is the HTML I have to work with at the moment.

```
<select name="parentList" size="8" multiple="" style="height:200px;font-size:11px;" ondblclick="MoveAcross(document.OrderForm['parentList'],document.OrderForm['updownlist']);">
<option value="O.247"> InfoCard Dataset- InfoCard Author</option>
```

Comment: Seems like a really easy thing to fix. If you wouldn't mind creating a jsfiddle out of it I would be happy to fix or alter it for you

Comment: You could do something like `$('option').filter((i, el) => /InfoCard (Author|Employee|File Name)$/.test(el.innerText)).prop('selected',true)`

Comment: E. Sundin,

With a little adjustment, this worked perfect! Cheers and many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:contains` selector to search for an element whose text includes certain text.

```
$("#leftSelect option:contains(InfoCard Employee)").prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: I don't think he's asking how to move the items.  Just how to select items based on what their label contains.

Comment: @TimothyKanski Thanks, I see that now. I've updated my answer to use the jQuery `:contains` selector.

Comment: I tweaked this also to: 

$('select[name=parentList] option:contains(InfoCard Dataset- InfoCard Employee)').prop('selected', true);

and it works fine. Cheers and many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function you can use to select all items that contain a string.

And a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TimothyKanski/8toya4h1/

```
function selectOptionsByNameContains(elementId, str){

  var ele = document.getElementById(elementId);
  var n = ele.options.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
    var text = ele.options[i].innerHTML
    console.log({text:text,str:str});
    if(text.includes(str)){
        $("#" + elementId).children().eq(i).attr('selected', true);
    }
  }

}
```